# RHEL 5, where is the SMTP configuration?

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I'm trying to change the SMTP settings of some of my RHEL5 servers as this servers are sending email via an exchange server which block any outgoing mail to external email IDs. Since changing the whole exchange server settings will impact many servers, one of the workaround suggested is to redirect my servers to use another exchange server which do not block any external outgoing emails.

I'm not familiar with the setup for RHEL5, however I did google around and most are talking about changing the configuration on /etc/mail.rc or /etc/postfix. Unfortunately I check the servers mail.rc file there's no SMTP value & also there's no postfix installed.

Anyone familiar with RHEL5 knows where exactly can I change the SMTP host? We're trying to make the server to send email via sendmail to an external email id.

Comment: Are you sure you are running postfix and not another MTA?  A crude way to find out the name of the running mta is `ps waux | grep \`sudo fuser -n tcp 25 | cut -f2\`    (including the right ticks) - This will find the process ID associated with the mail server listening on port 25 and then look what process has that ID.

Comment: There's no postfix package in the server. I even ran the ps command you ask but nothing came up. Server still able to send email to my working address, I tried to send 1 and I'm able to receive it.

Jun  2 14:22:23 server sendmail[3183]: 0526MMHJ003158: to=<me@company.com>, ctladdr=<root@server.com> (505/500), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=129585, relay=exch01.com. [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<202006020622.0526MMad003137@server.com> [InternalId=83833466653269, Hostname=exch03.com] 11252 bytes in 0.230, 47.606 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)

Comment: I wonder if you are using "Sendmail" (predates Postfix, still used in some places - Postfix used to bill itself as a drop-in replacement for Sendmail, but its soooo much easier to use.   I believe Sendmail stores its config in /etc/mail